# Ubuntu bash script output correct value - A script calls another script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a script that calls another script, but the output from the script seems to be wrong. Below is my code:

---

print_output.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
total=$(eval $1 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}')
echo "Total is $total"
```

---

try.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./print_output.sh "ssh $1 'cd /somelocation/logs; cat data-$1.txt' | grep ..."

Usuage is: ./try.sh ukdry-01
```

---

I expect the output to be:

```
uk
```

along with the "Total is 11" in this case. But the output is appearing as "cat data.txt".

Where I am going wrong? As I expect the input to be "ukdry-01". The "cat data.txt" is a command that be evaluated (i.e eval $1) from print_output.sh and executed within the script.

data.txt contains for example

```
1 AUTH
2 AND
8 BOOLEAN
```

The idea is that the total is printed. The script will ssh to a user inputted to an hostname i.e. ukdry-01, goes to data-ukdry-01.txt through cat and then logs out and performs a grep on the data found. The data is filtered is fed into print_output.sh which are all integers and prints out a total of column one. The usuage has to be the script name i.e. ./try.sh ukdry-01 where internally it calls ./print_output and then the ssh commands etc.

Comment: There's no `eval $1` anywhere in the posted code. It would be better to rewrite your question with the actual code, otherwise we might be solving the wrong problems.

Comment: It does look like it's doing exactly what you tell it to.  The string "cat data.txt" is the `$1` going into `print_output.sh`.  So that's what's being `echo`ed.

Comment: Note that `try.sh` script does not use any of its arguments therefore it could output the same string as its first positional argument only by coincidence.

Comment: Be sure to read and understand [Bash FAQ 048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) before going any further.

Comment: With the example described in the descripton, how would I get the value of "uk" as a parameter?

Comment: I have just edited my description with the code. Please help.

Comment: Please take a moment to *carefully* review your question. You updated the script without updating the expected output. `uk` is *never* going to be an expected sum of integers, which is what your updated script (in part) produces.

Comment: I have reviewed my question. Please take another look. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what had worked for me:

```
try.sh
#!/bin/bash
./print_output.sh $@ "ssh $1 'cd /somelocation/logs; cat data-$1.txt' | grep ..."

Usuage is: ./try.sh ukdry-01
```

The $@ copies the positional parameters and I can make use of ukdry-01 as $1.